# Evaluate $\prod_{n=2}^\infty(2-2^{1/n})$

Tags: limits, infinite-product

I tried telescoping the product but coudn't find a way to do so, any leads on how to evaluate this limit will help.
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}(2-2^{1/2})(2-2^{1/3})\cdots(2-2^{1/n})
$$

Comment: The product diverges to zero. Do you know how to deal with infinite products? What have you tried?